# Where in the Git documentation can I find :/

Tags: git

Git has this very useful feature of searching in previous commit messages with ":/" (colon slash) operator and picking up the first one that matches, e.g.:

```
git show :/"unique part of some previous commit message"
git commit --fixup :/"unique part of some previous commit message"
```

I've been using it for quite some time, but now I wanted to find it in the Git documentation (in pages like `git-show`, `got-commit`, `git-log` &c.) and couldn't. Anybody can point me in the right direction?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emlttextgtemegemfixnastybugem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in the documentation in [gitrevisions](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emlttextgtemegemfixnastybugem).